# I want to add a post to the woocommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to write long articles in the product categories that I created in woocommerce.  How do I add a post to each category separately? I want this post to appear after the products are listed in the category. Can I do this with any plugin or code? I would be very happy if you could help.

I tried many plugins but couldn't solve the problem.?

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we have two concepts:

1. product
2. post

and each of these two concepts has its own requirements. For example, we have `post-category` and `product-category`. You can use a condition to show posts located in `post-category-shoe` if the product category is equal to `product-cat-shoe`.

Let me make it clear with an example:
On one hand, you have a great article about ***how to choose a good running shoe***. on the other hand, you have 5 running shoes to sell in your woocommerce and named the category: ***running shoes***. Here are the solutions:

1. You introduce the shoes that you are selling inside the article you
   published in the `blog`.
2. You may create a section on the product category page and create a
   condition to show the title and excerpt of ***how to choose a good running shoe*** if the user checks this category: ***running shoes***.

Be careful using the same name for `product` and `post` categories may hurt your site's SEO. Finally, if I were you, I try to write a good description for the product category and redirect traffic from posts to the product with internal link building.

**Update:**

Based on more details you provide I noticed the problem. It is better to use `woocommerce_after_shop_loop` . Please try adding following line to `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'rabiei_display_content', 5 );
 
function rabiei_display_content() {
    if ( is_product_category('product-category') ) {
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
            'category_name' => 'post-category', 
            'posts_per_page' => 5 //number of post you want to display
        ) ); 
   
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $string .= '<ul>';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $string .= '<li>';
                    $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
                    } else { 
                    // if no featured image is found
                    $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
                    }
                    }
            } else {
            // no posts found
        $string .= '<li>No Posts Found</li>';
        }
$string .= '</ul>';
   
return $string;
   
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
   }
}
```

please replace `product-category` and `post-category` with the related slugs.

Comment: Hi Sallar, thank you for your reply. But that's not what I'm looking for. Actually what I want to do is this: I have a woocommerce site and I have categories attached in my menu. All of these categories are "product categories". It's not the regular wordpress category.
When my customers click on these categories, my products attached to those categories will appear. It will only appear in that product category section. It will not appear when you click on the product and enter it. I want to do something like this just to support the seo of the category link. But I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Ok, if I understand clearly, you want to make `Product Category` visible inside `product`? something like `breadcrumbs`. Would you please send a link to make it clear for me?

Comment: Please check the Example link.

Comment: The answer updated, please let me know if it is not what you want. If it works please click on the arrow up.

Comment: Hi Salar, thank you for your precious reply. But when I add this code to function.php it doesn't work correctly. I want to add separate articles for each category.

Each product category indicated by the arrows in the screenshot is independent of each other. When I click on each one, I want different articles and products added in that category to appear. 
But I don't want a post I shared on the blog to appear there. This article should only be added to the product category here. You can think of it as a description of all products.